# How to release and publish downloadable binaries?

Tags: c#, azure-devops

How do I configure Azure DevOps to publish binaries in a web downloadable form, and automatically update my readme.md or wiki page to reflect the latest released artifacts?

I know how to build release pipelines for artifacts I publish to Azure, e.g. I can publish webapps and functions.
But I can't figure out how to publish and release dowloadable content.

I'd like the result to be similar to GitHub releases, where my users can browse releases, and click and download the files.
I'd like the project page (readme.md or wiki) to automatically be updated with the release data, similar to how I would create a build state link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to upload the artifacts to your shared path. I recommend that you could add the script task to upload the released artifacts to the shared path or ftp server.

For example, if azure storage is acceptable, then you could publish your build artifacts to the Azure storage with following scripts

```
$source = "build file"
$azureStorageKey = "xxxxx"
$storage_context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "yourstorageAccount" -StorageAccountKey "$azureStorageKey"
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Context $storage_context -Container "containerName" -File $source -Blob "drop.zip" -Force
```

> I'd like the project page (readme.md or wiki) to automatically be updated with the release data, similar to how I would create a build state link.

Yes, you could to do that with Azure pipeline build state badge. You could copy the markdown link into your readme file

[image]

**Update :**

I do a demo upload the build to azure storage with following YAML file.

```
queue:

      name: Hosted VS2017
      demands: 
      - msbuild
      - visualstudio
      - azureps

    steps:
    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      displayName: 'NuGet restore'


    - task: VSBuild@1
      displayName: 'Build solution **\*.sln'


    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: 'Copy Files'
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)'

        TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'


    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'


    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'


    - task: AzureFileCopy@1
      displayName: 'AzureBlob File Copy'
      inputs:
        SourcePath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'

        azureSubscription: xxxxx

        Destination: AzureBlob

        storage: $(storageAccountName)

        ContainerName: $(containerName)
```

UI design:

[image]

> what I'd like is for the page to have a download link that points to the latest build that passed.

We could use  AzureBlob File Copy task to copy the build easily to the Azure blob storage.

If [Azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function) is possible, you could use the blob trigger to create your customized page with your script.

Comment: Thank you, the script is a good idea to go from artifacts to known location. As for the badge, I am already using build state badges, what I'd like is for the page to have a download link that points to the latest build that passed.

Comment: @PieterV I have updated the answer with a demo to publish the build zip file to azure storage. I recommend that you could use azure function blob trigger to create a page with your code.